# I can not see my Python Django server via an IP address while the localhost is working

Tags: python, django

I have written a server program using Python and Django and I have tested it in several computers. Now I have installed it on an [HP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewlett-Packard) server. While I can see that it is working when I type *localhost* in a browser address, when I type the server's IP address, I see *"This webpage is not available" (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)*.

The OS is [Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008). There isn't any antivirus software or firewall installed and the [Windows Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Firewall) is disabled.

It's noticeable that the messages that I send from my server program to some other devices in the network are successfully delivering. in other words, the connection is one-way (not duplex).

Comment: Are you running the django development server? You should start it with startserver 0.0.0.0:8000, the 0's indicate that you can reach it from outside

Comment: @user1797792 You are right. I changed the IP that was not started with 0 and this solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good, I've posted this as an answer, so other people can easily see the solution. If you could mark it as the Answer it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Django development server:

> To make your development server viewable to other machines on the
> network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or ::
> (with IPv6 enabled).

So, your command will look something like

```
runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: What are you quoting? It is [allegedly from the official documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606084/setting-up-a-django-development-server-that-can-be-accessed-by-other-devices-on). But where?