# Setting up a Django development server that can be accessed by other devices on my network

Tags: python, django, server

I want to set up a Django development server that both my computers and smart phones can access whilst on my network via Wi-Fi.

I've already set up a development server that my computer can access on http://127.0.0.1:8000/.  However, my other devices can't.

The Django documentation says:

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network. To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).

I've found my "public IP address" and tried to use this by:

```
python manage.py runserver xx.xx.xxx.x
```

(where this is my public IP address), but I get a "Command error: 'xx.xx.xxx.x' is not a valid port number or address:port pair."

I then tried the same with :8000 after the IP address, but I got an error: "Error: That IP address can't be assigned to".

Then

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000.
```

The command line reports "Starting development server at ...", but when I try "http://0.0.0.0:8000/" on Chrome, I get a "This site can't be reached error".

Has it something to do with my Windows firewall settings?

Comment: try with http://xx.xx.xxx.x:8000. Also do you have two Django servers running at the same time? Could you post the exact errors you are getting?

Comment: Hi @elena, with my development server set to 0.0.0.0:8000, I have just tried http://xx.xx.xxx.x:8000, but the Chrome page is just "thinking" with no result or error.  I just have the one Django development server running - i stop it before trying another python command on the command line.  i have updated my original post with the exact errors.  Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.0.0.0 is not a real address; it's a placeholder that just says that the server is not bound to a specific IP address.

If you run on 127.0.0.1, it will only answer to queries that where addressed to 127.0.0.1, so [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) only.

Using your private address (192.168.0.x most often), it will only answer to queries to this address (so opening with the 127.0.0.1 should not work, but it sometimes does depend on the implementation).

So, if you use 0.0.0.0, it will answer to anything.

tl;dr: use 0.0.0.0 and connect using:

- 127.0.0.1 from this computer
- your computer's private IP address for other computers inside your [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network)
- your public IP address for computers outside your LAN. Note that this will require additional configuration on your router

Comment: Hi, thank you for explaining.  I just googled how to find my computer's private ip address.  I used the command "ipconfig" on the command line to get my "IPv4 Address" which is 192.xxx.x.xxx.  (not 168.0.0.x).  So having started the development server at 0.0.0.0:8000, I tried my 192.xxx.x.xxx address in my smart phone.  Its given me a long Django-looking error starting "Disallowed host at /...".  with a suggested solution to add my private ip address to "Allowed_hosts".  I'll work out how to do this as soon as i can...

Comment: I added my computer's private IP address as a string to the empty list of allowed hosts of the settings.py file.  Problem solved! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I run onto an additional issue following this post. If you are using a [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux)-based Linux distribution and if *[firewalld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewalld)*
is enabled, it might be blocking the connection. So for testing purposes, run:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need your local IP address to be not public.
You can get the local IP address on a Windows machine by typing the following command in [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe): `ipconfig` .

On Linux, type the following in the terminal: `ifconfig`

The IP address will be of the form **192.168.0.101[Example]**

So in your phone's browser, type: **192.168.0.101:8000**

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 defaults to the localhost of the system.

So connecting with that address from another device, is telling that device to connect to itself. You can use your IP address, but in other for Django to allow it, go to your projects *settings.py* file.

You should see an option ALLOWED_HOSTS = []. Put in your IP address in quotes, e.g., '192.168.xxx.xxx'. Save it and when next you want to run the server, add the *ipaddress:8000* after issuing the command. This will allow Django to host your site on your computer's IP address, but only devices on the same wifi can access it.

The scope of that is beyond the question. You might also need to allow Django to bypass your system's firewall.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).