# Docker Error - CommandError: "0.0.0.0:" is not a valid port number or address:port pair

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

So I have a docker file, that I intend to build and push to Google Cloud Run and it looks like this:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7-slim

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

The idea is that once I push it to Cloud Run, my Django project will run on 0.0.0.0:$PORT, where the value of the environment variable $PORT is set by Google Cloud Run automatically.

I tried to run a container of the following image locally to see if this works. I set $PORT to 80, and then when I run a container of the docker image I get the following:

```
"CommandError: "0.0.0.0:" is not a valid port number or address:port pair."
```

Looking at other answers, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606084/setting-up-a-django-development-server-that-can-be-accessed-by-other-devices-on).

I understand that 0.0.0.0 is a placeholder for the public IP address of a given machine. My question is, why doesn't do I get the "CommandError" when I run `docker run [DockerImage]` locally??

If there are any other questions, please let me know I will clarify it.

Edit:
I also want to point out that I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@lhennessy/running-django-on-google-cloud-run-with-cloudsql-ac8141095b77)

Comment: $PORT isn't set where it's being expanded. So either it's being expanded by docker while processing the Dockerfile (read the docs for CMD) or Cloud Run isn't setting it like you say.

Comment: Just to double-check, did you set the $PORT environment variable on your local machine? On Cloud Run it is set automatically but for local execution you have to set it yourself.

Comment: @LundinCast yes I had set it locally but it was not in the Dockerfile!

Comment: You said `0.0.0.0 is a placeholder for the public IP address`. This is wrong. The IP address `0.0.0.0` is a convention that means listen on all IPv4 network interfaces. If a system has more than one IPv4 network interface, this convention means listen on each network interface. Note that this convention only applies to creating listen sockets (which wait for inbound connection attempts) and not for outbound connections.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Setting the environment variable on host machine doesn't set it inside the container.

The command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT` is being run inside the container where `$PORT` is not set and so it expands to `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:`.

Try `docker run -e PORT=$PORT <your_image>` to pass set the `PORT` env variable inside the container with value from the host machine.

Answer (score 10):

You have not set the `PORT` env variable in the Dockerfile and that's the reason its failing to resolve `$PORT` during CMD execution.

you can update your Dockerfile as follow (I have used `8080` as an example, update this to required port):

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7-slim

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PORT 8080

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I would select this as the best answer but the person above's had already worked. Thanks though - I think this would be a good reference for people in the future.